# How to parse Industry Foundation Class (IFC) files using Java?

Tags: java, ifc

I want to develop an application, which has to parse the Industry Foundation Class (IFC) generated by the Auto CAD software and render the 3D images in an applet window using Java. I have no idea about how to do it.If anybody knows the solution, please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can study the IfcOpenShell code. Basically IFCOpenShell makes the executable C++ classes. So first you need to read IFC into any computer language which you think then you have to load it into memory.

follow this link:http://ifcopenshell.org/

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.

Comment: hope this is not now.

Comment: The main thing is still on the external site.

Comment: Pardon? I am unable to get you.

Answer (score 1):

[JSDAI](http://www.jsdai.net/) seems also very promising

From the website:

> JSDAI™ is an Application Programming Interface (API) for reading, writing and runtime manipulation of object oriented data defined by an EXPRESS based data model. Such models are widely used in STEP (ISO 10303), PLIB (ISO 13584) and other ISO, IEC and DIN standards.